# Questions that ask about tutorials or How to do something without showing code

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, questions, downvotes

> I want to make X but I don't know what programming language I need, or
>   what framework I should use, and I need some Links for tutorials about them.

I have seen some questions, these questions just asking about tutorials.. specially new users.

Is this kind of questions welcome on Stack Overflow? Is It fine to vote it down ?

Comment: For the record, you can downvote anything for any reason you like.

Comment: I wish there was a Stack Exchange site for these types of questions. As a newer programmer, I have them very frequently, and spend so much time just settling on a tool...when people who have used many tools could offer their insights gained after so much sweat and tears. It's weird, because the questions are often answerable, but for some reason they are considered inappropriate for SO, but answers would save programmers lots of time exploring different garden paths. They are clearly incredibly popular (e.g., see the 'Which IDE should I use for Python'), so the demand is there..

Comment: @neuronet Try [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but make sure you phrase your question to be [on topic for that site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). That said, it might not be a good idea to ask about programming languages, but more which framework to use once you've chosen a language

Comment: @neuronet Except that type of question doesn't really work on SO - the system doesn't guarentee good answers, and users will expect a quality of answer they won't get when they hit the question on Google. On the other hand, these kind of questions *are* well answered by a quick google - lots of blog posts and the like, which are best for this kind of thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get slammed for asking 'which tool/approach' questions, when the exact same type of question lives on on the forums, and sometimes the subject is quite close. "We can't suggest solutions/products/etc." is a typical rationale, if one is given at all. "I want to create X... Where do start?" questions should have a place, especially if the OP lists tools/languages they are already good at... Why CAN'T I get advice instead of a yes/no?

Comment: So you're kinda asking for a tutorial on voting down?  I'll up vote that.

Comment: Sometimes i vote the down, sometimes i don't. It depends on the user and their history. If they haven't contributed anything, and just take and take from the community, i'll neg them. But if they have been helpful in the past i like to give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @r3wt voting down does not depend on history (ever never), It depends on the question itself and if that question is suitable to ask on SO or not only. :)

Comment: Since this question normally required nothing more than Googling the question this question would not be suitable on any other SE stie. There is no point in ditching such a question in software recs because it will just damage their community, instead vote to close, in fact we should have a close reason of: "Google it"

Comment: @PatTrainor being able to provide your own resources as a programmer is essential, i.e. until recently I didn't know Python. Instead of asking people to Google for me on this site I instead took the initiative to actually do it myself. And now I can program python

Comment: @Sammaye In a short comment, there is more than enough room for misinterpretation. Recently I wanted the community's opinion on the best way to do a globe in WPF as a user-interface/display. It was shot down because users aren't allowed to recommend software. That is the kind of thing I'm talking about. I should not be penalized for asking in a forum of experts the same exact question I'd ask if we were all sitting together talking. SO moderation (official or user-based) is too critical, and not supportive enough. They enforce the letter of the rules to spite the spirit/intent of the same.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> I want to make X but I don't know what programming language I need, or what framework I should use, and I need some Links for tutorials about them.

There are lots of problems with this:

- **too broad**: It does not even narrow it down to a single programming language...
- **recommend or find a favorite tool or off site resource**: It asks for tutorials
- **primarily opinion based**: It is about opinions from the programming language choice to the recommendation.

So, no, these types of questions are not welcome here, and yes, closing and downvoting would be correct in this case and please do so.

---

The question may be *better* suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ since it would not be a problem of *recommending a favorite tool or off site resource*, but it would still not fit the site.  At the *very* least, a programming language specification would need to be added to the question first.  Also, it is always a good idea to read the [how to ask](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section before posting to assure that the requirements are met.

Comment: Would you consider linking to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead then?

Comment: @JBert It may be a *better* fit for that site, but it would still be a bad question because it is very broad since it does not even specify the programming language.

Comment: What do the softwarerecs people think about this? Do they agree? In some cases the have asked to be sure that the question is right for their site.

I see the point. But a Software recommendation is not the same as a tutorial recommendation.

Answer (score 34):

> Is this kind of questions welcome on Stack Overflow?

No, this kind of question is not welcome on Stack Overflow.

> Is It fine to vote it down ?

It is. It also fine to vote to close it (if you have the reputation to cast close and reopen votes). We actually have a specific close reason for asking for off site resources like tutorials and such...

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, this kind of questions (don't know what programming language I need, or what framework I should use, and I need some Links for tutorials about them) speaks more about the guy asking for help than about his problem.

There is a fair and professional approach to technical issues and learning, which SO tries to convey and there is a superficial, "quickie", "hand me a free meal now!" other approach.

Now, don't get me wrong, I am not saying SO is a resource for professionals only, it's totally for everyone! What I am saying - and it's very apt for this meta section - is the *mindset* approach to problems, which may be professional / serious or shallow, superficial.

A true newbie who has a serious mindset performs his due diligence, Googles a bit, tries to cobble an idea of solution together first. Then if he does not succeed, he comes to SO with his rough draft and (often) gets even more help than he hoped to get in the first place.

The other kind of person, is not really somebody who wants to learn. It's somebody who got tasked solving some problem he does not really care for and does not want to spend any time on, so he comes to SO to claim a canned solution worked (and time / effort spent) by somebody else, like a bloodsucker.

Imo the former deserve all SO support possible. Yes, he did not succeed solving his own issue on his own but he really tried and one day he'll be a first candidate to open somebody else on SO himself.

The latter deserves downvoting and post closed. He did not even try to approach a solution, he wants others to work for him (parasite / squatter mentality) and he's not ever going to help anyone else on SO later, his post will probably be the only "contribution" to SO he'll ever do.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Can we automatically guide programming newbies to the tag-wikis for tutorials?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261867/can-we-automatically-guide-programming-newbies-to-the-tag-wikis-for-tutorials?cb=1) for an interesting possible approach to questions like this.

Answer (score -6):

In general, I agree with all opinions expressed so far (I'm not equivocating, let me explain...).

I've been in this industry for over 30 years, and I know what's it's like for someone who is just getting started.  It's very easy to get immediately overwhelmed with the wealth of environments and solutions out there, and doing a generic web search usually gets you more garbage than useable information.

A site like this is where most of the professionals who know what they're doing recommend that noobs search for information, but, again, noobs don't necessarily know what question to ask or search for.

@neuronet had a great suggestion: dedicate a new section of this exchange for people who are just learning.  There's no problem with not knowing what to ask, and experienced professionals should have the patience to educate "the young", otherwise this becomes an elitist site and will wither into atrophy.  Instead of downgrading these requests, they should be redirected to the new section, basically saying "this area is a little too advanced for your request, but you would probably find the help that you need here...".

I've always made sure that I don't treat any question as "wrong", if the asker has the courage to ask for help, then they should at least be treated seriously.  If someone is asking "do this for me", however, that's a different matter.  Asking for help is one thing; asking for someone else to do your job for you is something else entirely.

Comment: It's fairly pathetic that someone would downvote this response without adding a comment, so much for an open exchange of information....

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it's worth pointing out that on the Meta sites, many people use their votes to indicate "I agree with this" or "I disagree with this", in which case a comment would be superfluous.

Comment: thank you, David, I meant no offense...

Comment: It's fairly pathetic that you would deem somebody disagreeing with you as "fairly pathetic"; so much for an open exchange of viewpoints....

Comment: Why should experienced professionals be patient with people who lack the common courtesy of doing basic research before they ask their questions?  People *should* have some idea of what they want before they ask.  Adding yet another SE site dedicated to those who have no clue what they're doing isn't going to help anything, they're still going to dump their trash on SE.

Answer (score -15):

I think this is the kind of question beginners should ask: "I want to make this and that. What kind of programming language or method would you recommend?" Asking for tutorials is a very different thing however, because once one knows the generally recommended language or method, searching the interweb for such tutorials is a piece of cake.

I would be careful with downvoting. There is a world of difference between asking for advice on language or method and "My [object] doesn't work. Help!" Those questions must be downvoted.

Unless SO wants to principally bar beginners, but I would find that harsh. We all once started. Some after having done a proper coding course, some even after having gone through coding university, but many by self-education. For those people, I find questions asking for general advice totally appropriate.

I mean, what time and effort does it cost us to answer such a question? Exactly: zero, zilch, very little at the most.

Comment: You're wrong. This has nothing to do with expertise level... nothing at all. Such questions from advanced users would be wrong, too. It's about _what is and isn't suitable for a Q&A_. I don't know why I have to keep explaining this over and over again but Stack Overflow is not a forum. If you want to have a conversation or get advice or mentoring, there are other places for that.

Comment: `Unless SO wants to principally bar beginners` - it does basically. The tag line is "a site for professional and enthusiast programmers". A beginner doesn't really come under that umbrella - nor should they. With 30 seconds of searching, _all beginner questions_ are already answered on SO.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Then who decides when a user is no longer a beginner?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: just have a look at the CSS questions. I estimate that 90% of those questions are beginners questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: define "forum"?

Comment: @FrankConijn Not this. SO is more like a giant, collaborative FAQ. Though many people keep trying to faq that up -.-

Comment: If it takes zero time, I suppose they answer themselves. If the questions answer themselves they can be asked anywhere. Do it in your cat's sandbox. We'll stick to the interesting questions that don't take zero time to answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: that's no definition.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: a question like "I wanna make this and that. Which method or language would you recommend?" doesn't answer itself.

Comment: @FrankConijn: Well, I'm not a free dictionary service. Look it up.