# Can we automatically guide programming newbies to the tag-wikis for tutorials?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tag-wiki

I'm sure I'm not the only one seeing a large number of *"Im a newbie in XXX, please explain what this does..."*

In most cases they are not programming issues, but rather lack of reading tutorials, books or doing minimal research -- most of the major tag-wiki's has a very good tutorial and reference links, however, the wikis are not obvious or easy to find, unless you are intimate with Stack Exchange -- so for new users never get to this information.

New users are however largely able to correctly tag their questions -- I'm not sure if this is a conscious effort, or part of the automatic tag suggestion -- probably a bit of both.

So rather than having to discuss the validity of these questions, why not try to guide the users to some of this highly curated and useful information -- so similar to the automatic search which happens when you ask a new question, why not throw up a page with the relevant parts of the wikis -- showing where to find language references guides, tutorials etc.

Now, not all tag-wikis have curated help content -- so a technical difficulty would be to identify which wikis have the quality information.  Also a criteria for who should be shown this information -- new users, users with small rep, first time for a tag question, etc?

Comment: I would show them the tag wikis corresponding to their question if it contains things like `noob`, `n00b`, `beginner`, `newb`, `tutorial` unless they have about 500 rep, for their first 3 questions unconditionally. If none of those tag-wikis have good content, it's just about guaranteed they asked a bad question...

Comment: I was thinking of text matching as the conditional for show the wiki-info, but my experience such rule based system opens up a maintains nightmare of maintaining a hot list, and then managing exceptions -- anecdoteably hotlist was used to prevent users creating account with objectionable names such as containing "god" -- while showing wiki information would not prevent anything, then it has the possibility of creating annoyance for false-positives -- hence an simpler and easier rule system would be my preference.

Comment: Poor Godot, now he has to wait too ;-)

Comment: there are tag wikis? wow. good to know. Seriously. I just found them after reading this. I have clicked on tags plenty of times, but always brought to list of questions. Never clicked the 'about' tab before. Maybe make that the default when new members click on a tag, so we learn it is there.

Comment: @neuronet -- That could be an option as well -- however the tags is the last which is filled in, i.e. after the OP has written the question -- so they are less likely to use this help -- human nature is to just get the darn question posted, and skip all the hint/tips/messages.   I think an option would be to ask for the TAGs before the Question-writing box -- then you could guide the user to the resources before the question is written, and maybe the user will read the content.

Comment: @Soren Tags-first would also be helpful if tags could define a short popup - e.g. the postgresql tag would say *"remember to include `select version()` output plus exact error message text or `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)`"*

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you'll find much traction with any "force the users to..." suggestion.  Heck, they won't even force users to choose a name when registering ;)  I think a lot of users don't even know they CAN choose a name.

There's also the fact that users simply won't read, even if you put things in blinking red lights.  See http://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/

I agree wholeheartedly about making the tag-wiki more discoverable, maybe even adding a "check the Wiki" kind of link in the questions that show up as possible duplicates...  Perhaps we can even have as the first result in a search a link to the topic-wiki.

Beyond subtle suggestion, however, I think you'll get a lot of pushback.

Comment: My intent would not be to force anybody to do anything, but just make this site a more useful place but surfacing the information which can teach people to program in their chosen language.   Most of the newbie questions are really just lacking a tutorial or research, and they have come to the site because they have typed some random programming verbs into Google which then gave SO as the top answer -- I think it would be worth while making sure that new users have easy access to the curated information on the tag-wikis

Comment: I have done my fair bit in Advertising -- and after reading Jeff's blog post listed above, I can see why people don't read the help hint -- it is the same reason people are getting ad-blindness -- so presenting people with more helps and tools, like our tag-wikis, needs to be designed in a way were it is not just more information on the same screen, but rather something constructive which people are being guide through -- I admit that this would not be without difficulty, but the mission of the site is to be a resource for programmers, so surfacing this information should be worth it.

Comment: @Soren - The "automatically guide..." bit is the same thing as forcing them to specific content, and that's what I meant that you would get pushback from.

Comment: FWIW, I'm just past being a noob and I would have found this really helpful. Also FWIW, I've been on the site for a couple years and I didn't know about the tag-wikis. In fact, I'd probably STILL find it helpful.

Comment: Your answer led me to make this suggestion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265374/1313143.

Answer (score 2):

> So rather than having to discuss the validity of these questions, why
>   not try to guide the users to some of this highly curated and useful
>   information -- so similar to the automatic search which happens when
>   you ask a new question, why not throw up a page with the relevant
>   parts of the wikis -- showing where to find language references
>   guides, tutorials etc.

Great idea. But we are in the year 2014. There are tons of tutorials online & tons of printed material that can help anyone learn the basics of anything. Seriously. If someone with this much rich content can’t find out how to code on their own—and somehow need some parochial mentor to force them to learn—they are already behind a ball of their own creation.

Or more generally: Have you ever worked in any form retail or customer service? You learn fairly quickly that human behavior often dictates that when someone desires help, they actually will seek out someone else to do work for them. Now I am not saying all of us are like this, but the reality is most people want to be “served” which is a whole sociological discussion in & of itself.

Which can be summed up as follows: A healthy sense of humility—where one admits they are lost, needs help & when pointed in the right direction will be independent—does not exist in many poster’s to this site or even any other online community. Trying to force “education” will never work. The best you can do is post a well worded & clear answer, maybe point to some online resource—or other answer here—and hope for the best.

Past that if they are clingy, what can you do other than respond to a comment by saying, “Sorry, but I have helped you as best as I can.  Best of luck!” Some people will be helpless here, there, elsewhere & decades from now. And it’s not your problem on how to solve their inability to help themselves.

Be fair, set boundaries, move on.

Comment: While we are in 2014 -- then people still don't do research very well -- as simple thing a sticking your question into a search engine is probably not done by many, or if they do they will get StackOverflow as a top answer which promise them to help them for free.   Your point of that there are many online tutorial available is very valid, however we already have the resources curated and available in the wiki pages -- but we don't show them, as tag-wikis are very hard to find -- and most of our users probably don't even know they exists.  I want to make that content more prominent.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials online, and 99.98% of them are junk that teach bad habits.

Comment: @BenVoigt -- true, that is why SO curate the best information on tag-wikis and we should make sure our new users are getting easy access to that information

Comment: When you are new in a given subject it is often hard to know what to search for to get good answers.  Saying "why didn't you search for this?" first, indicates the asker had forgotten that.

Comment: @Thorbj&#248;rnRavnAndersen Or they may've read outdated / bad material and become even more confused.

Comment: @CraigRinger type "@Thor" and TAB to have my name autocompleted... Correctly!  This is one of the really nice things that SE just introduced under the covers.

Comment: The name mangling is a bug in the mobile app's "reply" feature. I expected it to decode the entities on submit.

Answer (score 2):

The people who're popping up with those questions:

- Are struggling to understand info they've already been shown (and thus probably won't benefit from the wikis they're linked to);
- Want to be spoon-fed info (and thus won't read the wikis etc they're linked to);
- Have misunderstood some key concept (so they will probably misunderstand the wiki content too); or
- just have terrible search skills (in which case they might actually benefit from the wiki links).

Overall, I don't see much benefit to this proposal.

Closing things as dups by pointing them at canonical answers is a much better strategy where it's a clear duplicate - this also often makes it easier to find good answers from multiple different entry points / different search terms.

Where it isn't a duplicate but seems like basic material - that's why we have "too broad" and "unclear what you're asking". I'm not sure what this proposal really adds over those. Maybe link to the tag wiki(s) from the close banner on those close types instead?

I don't want to see closing as "read the damn wiki" becoming an automatic reflex action. Sometimes people will have and will be confused. Or struggle to understand. A short explanation of what they have misunderstood can help reduce repeat questions later - or so I've found on the PostgreSQL tag anyway. Similarly, dup-closes provide different ways to find the same answers.

Instead let's make the tag wiki links prominently visible in the closed-as-duplicate, closed-as-too-broad, closed-as-opinion-based and closed-as-unclear banners.

To get creative could even add sections accessible as fragment identifiers (tag/info#unclear) in the tag wiki so headings covering each category can be created for busy tags. For example: tags/PostgreSQL/info#opinion would rapidly grow an explanation on "Why your question on whether MySQL/Oracle/MS-SQL/etc is faster/slower than PostgreSQL just got closed" section.

I'd really like to have automatic tag wiki links to headings (via fragment identifiers) from close banners, actually.

Comment: While I agree that there is probably a fair amount of laziness and uselessness involved in some peoples motivation, then I would like to believe in the better of people, and at least help those who are willing to learn given the right resources -- if that is only 10% of people, we will reduce the noise and improve the quality of questions.  If I extrapolate you opinion we should at least have a close-reason which would include a link to the twiki, like *'This question can probably be answered if you read the material listed on this page <link to tag-wiki>`* -- less proactive & less helpful

Comment: @Soren I just don't want to see close-with-tag-wiki-ref be the automatic reflex action. It isn't necessarily going to help. Sometimes clearing up one person's confusion/misunderstanding helps others later. Certainly found that on the PostgreSQL tag. If the question is an obvious repeat we have dup-close already and if it's total nonsense we have unclear-what-you're-asking. So I don't see what value this proposal offers. Maybe auto-link to the tag wiki from the unclear close page instead?

Comment: @Soren Clarified the answer.